# List comprehension to remove element from python list if it is only digits (even if there are "_" or "-" in it)

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have many lists like this

```
synonyms = ["3,2'-DIHYDROXYCHALCONE", '36574-83-1', '36574831', "2',3-Dihydroxychalcone",  '(E)-1-(2-hydroxyphenyl)-3-(3-hydroxyphenyl)prop-2-en-1-one', MLS002693861]
```

from which I need to remove all elements that are comprised of only digits. I can't figure out how to remove element `[1]` because it's only digits but has random intervening dashes.

Of course, this doesn't work since the dashes make the element not a digit:

```
synonym_subset = [x for x in synonym_subset if not (x.isdigit())]
```

And I can't just remove the dashes because I want the dashes in the other elements to be retained:

```
synonym_subset = [x.replace('-','') for x in synonym_subset]
```

I could run the above to find the index of the elements to be removed, then remove them that way, but I was hoping for a one-liner.

Thanks.

Comment: If a string has *just* hyphens and underscores and *no* digits, what do you want to do with it? For example, what should happen to `'-'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
synonyms = [
    "3,2'-DIHYDROXYCHALCONE",
    "36574-83-1",
    "36574831",
    "2',3-Dihydroxychalcone",
    "(E)-1-(2-hydroxyphenyl)-3-(3-hydroxyphenyl)prop-2-en-1-one",
    "MLS002693861",
]

out = [s for s in synonyms if not all(ch in "0123456789-_" for ch in s)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    "3,2'-DIHYDROXYCHALCONE",
    "2',3-Dihydroxychalcone",
    "(E)-1-(2-hydroxyphenyl)-3-(3-hydroxyphenyl)prop-2-en-1-one",
    "MLS002693861",
]
```

Comment: Why is `_` in the string?

Comment: @Barmar The OP stated in the title he doesn't want `-` or `_`

Comment: Similar: `[s for s in synonyms if s.strip("0123456789-_")]`

Answer (score 2):

As a minor addition to the already posted replies, depending on the length of such strings, it could make sense to use set() - for instance:

```
synonyms = [
    "3,2'-DIHYDROXYCHALCONE",
    "36574-83-1",
    "36574831",
    "2',3-Dihydroxychalcone",
    "(E)-1-(2-hydroxyphenyl)-3-(3-hydroxyphenyl)prop-2-en-1-one",
    "MLS002693861",
]

myset = set("0123456789-_")
[s for s in synonyms if not set(s).issubset(myset)]
```

Edit: As mentioned by @no comment, this can be improved further by using `issuperset` like so:

```
isdigits = set("0123456789-_").issuperset
[s for s in synonyms if not isdigits(s)]
```

Each gives:

```
["3,2'-DIHYDROXYCHALCONE", "2',3-Dihydroxychalcone", '(E)-1-(2-hydroxyphenyl)-3-(3-hydroxyphenyl)prop-2-en-1-one', 'MLS002693861']
```

P.S. Another way would be using the ord(), but this is typically slower and of course it is less readable:

```
[s for s in synonyms if not all(ord(k) in (*range(48,58),45,95) for k in s)]
```

Comment: I think `issuperset` is faster, don't even need to convert `s` to a set then and can short circuit.

Comment: Like, `isdigits = set("0123456789-_").issuperset` and then `[s for s in synonyms if not isdigits(s)]`.

Comment: I like it, I'll edit my answer and add this, if you're okay with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) [edit: although in this case you probably shouldn't, as mentioned in the comments]:

```
import re

synonyms = [
    "3,2'-DIHYDROXYCHALCONE",
    "36574-83-1",
    "36574831",
    "2',3-Dihydroxychalcone",
    "(E)-1-(2-hydroxyphenyl)-3-(3-hydroxyphenyl)prop-2-en-1-one",
    "MLS002693861",
]

filtered_synonyms = list(
    filter(lambda x: not re.sub(r"[-_]", "", x).isdigit(), synonyms)
)
```

Results in:

```
["3,2'-DIHYDROXYCHALCONE", "2',3-Dihydroxychalcone", '(E)-1-(2-hydroxyphenyl)-3-(3-hydroxyphenyl)prop-2-en-1-one', 'MLS002693861']
```

Comment: @AndrejKesely `list(filter(lambda` is an anti-pattern in general, and the question asks for a list comprehension and already has one that's almost right.

Comment: Oh and it doesn't handle "_".

Comment: @nocomment Fair points. I do agree that the list comprehension is more readable, but there was already an answer using that, and I just wanted to add one with a different way of achieving the same result. But why do you say `list(filter(lambda` is an antipattern? Could you point me to any good resources about that?

Comment: @e-motta: `filter` in general is lightly frowned upon (the creator of the language wanted to remove it, or at least hide it in a module, in the Py3 transition, but enough objected to keep it). It's justifiable when you already have an existing function to do the work, as that function presumably has a self-documenting name and, especially if it's a built-in implemented in C, can run a tiny bit faster using `filter`. But if you're using a `lambda` that could have been inlined into an equivalent listcomp or genexpr, you get the worst of all worlds: The code is slower *and* less readable.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Meh, I don't mind `filter` in general, it's the combination with `lambda` for the reasons you stated plus lack of flexibility, and then the `list` adds insult to injury :-P. But for example I'd find `list(filter(re.compile(r"[^0-9_-]").search, synonyms))` ok.

Comment: @nocomment: Yes, like I said, it's only *lightly* frowned upon in general (I personally like it for specific use cases like yours, but Guido is not a fan). I use `map` and `filter` all the time *with an existing function implemented in C*, but if I need a `lambda`, it's listcomp or genexpr.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Has Guido said that recently? I only know [this](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) from 19 years ago.

Comment: @nocomment: I don't think he needs to repeat it? He acquiesced to keeping them, but he thought `filter` was so useless it would be uncontroversial to drop it back then. I don't see his opinion having changed dramatically since.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Well, opinions *can* change, and it's been a long time. Back then I even thought PHP is good.